# Getting this error 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException' while running test for Android

Tags: android, python-3.x, appium, pytest

I am in need of your expertise..
I am trying to automate a simple test case, using Python, Appium framework, I am facing this problem trying to refactor your code to use page object model approach. Using Pytest as test Runner. I am receiving this error below, I am new to these technologies please help me to decipher this enigma. Thank you.

**for reference, this test case passed successfully before refactoring, here is the piece code :**

```
def test_item_details_page(driver):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((MobileBy.XPATH, '//android.widget.TextView[@index=2]'))).click()
    assert wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((MobileBy.XPATH, '//android.widget.TextView[@text="Item Facts"]'))).text == "Item Facts"
```

```
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py:80: TimeoutException
```

So far I have these 3 files on my project folder:
conftest.py

```
import pytest 
from os import path
from appium import webdriver

CUR_DIR = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
APP = path.join(CUR_DIR, 'app.apk')
APPIUM = 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub'

@pytest.fixture
def driver():
    CAPS = {
    'platformName': 'Android',
    'platformVersion': '11.0',
    'deviceName': 'Pixel 3',
    'automationName': 'UIAutomator2',
    'app': APP,
    }

  
    driver = webdriver.Remote(APPIUM, CAPS)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

home_view.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class HomeView(object):

    GEM_ITEM = (MobileBy.XPATH, '//android.widget.TextView[@index=2]')

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver  

 
    def nav_to_details_page(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        #self to access to the class variable
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(self.GEM_ITEM)).click()
```

test_detail_page.py

```
from appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import MobileBy
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from views.home_view import HomeView


def test_item_details_page(driver):

    # instantiate the page object

    home = HomeView(driver)
    home.nav_to_details_page

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    assert wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((MobileBy.XPATH, '//android.widget.TextView[@text="Item Facts"]'))).text == "Item Facts"
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I realized that I was missing a () in this line:

```
home.nav_to_details_page()
```

Thank you.